# Loading a .less file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

When I run the rails app, am getting an error that says **cannot load such file -- less**.,

I have a rails application that I'm using to load an html file., this html file has reference to bootstrap_and_overrides.css. My current rails application is using the typical application.html.erb file. Here is the code for this file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyHorders</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="masthead">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="muted">blog.me</h3>
    </div>

    <%= yield %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My css and assets directory structure is :

[image]

[image]

Finally my GEM env.,

[image]

Looking for inputs to quash this problem. If you will need more information, I can add it to my question., Thanks.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: Thanks, that was long-time ago. I don't remember it anymore. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need two gems

```
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"
```

add them to your Gemfile and run 'bundle install' then restart your server and see it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try

```
gem "execjs"
```

If you have any issue

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to restart my server. I had added several related gems to my Gemfile (less-rails, therubyracer, and twitter-bootstrap-rails) while my local server was running, resulting in the same problem seen above. So once I shut it down and restarted it again, everything loaded well.